# Invoking a Method on All Elements in an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, loops, iterator, concurrentmodification

I'm trying to call the `closeScreen` method for all the `EntityPlayer` objects in the `playersUsing` array list but I keep running into a ConcurrentModificationException. Iv'e tried every single thing I could think of and its even thrown when I use an iterator. I realize this could possibly be a duplicate but iv'e looked through a ton of questions and none of them have helped me so far. I don't have access to the `EntityPlayer` class so I can't change any of the code from it. Here's what I'm working with at the moment:

```
    Iterator<EntityPlayer> iterator = playersUsing.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        EntityPlayer player = iterator.next();
        player.closeScreen();
        System.out.println("CLOSED: " + player.username);
        iterator.remove();
    }
```

EDIT: (Here is the `closeScreen` method):

```
public void closeScreen()
{
    this.openContainer = this.inventoryContainer;
}
```

Comment: I realize this does not answer the question, but why do you need to remove them all in the loop? You could execute `closeScreen()` on every element and then call `clear()` on the list.

Comment: @Joffrey its unnecessary. By then I was just trying random things in hopes that something would work.

Comment: Something would work to do what? If all you need is calling `closeScreen()` on every player, then just remove the `iterator.remove()`. But anyway, this should not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. Do you have another piece of code running at the same time and modifying the list? Where is the exception thrown exactly?

Comment: @Joffrey I didn't think so but now that i'm really thinking about it... its possible that player.closeScreen() might call the same method that I'm using to remove players from the array list. Im going to test that now.

Comment: That would totally make sense to have the exception then. You might want to reconsider the organization of your code maybe. Why would a player have access to the list?

Comment: What is the type of `playersUsing` ??

Comment: @hagrawal EntityPlayer

Comment: You mean array of EntityPlayer ??

Comment: @hagrawal yes, an ArrayList

Comment: @Joffrey It seems as though that was the issue, but I took a look at the closeScreen method (I put the code in my question) and I really don't see how that can call a method before my loop finishes? The only thing I can think of is that EntityPlayer could be being used in another thread. Do you think that's probably the issue?

Comment: @kmecpp If `playerUsing` is a list you created yourself, and `PlayerEntity` is not aware of that list, then it can't possibly interact with it. Do you control the list? You're not passing it to the players in any way, right? Are you sure your exception comes from a modification of this list? Could you please post the stack trace and explain the line references?

Comment: @kmecpp I guess you are using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` for `EntityPlayer ` list. Right ?? That's the only chance I see and if that is the case then you would be getting exception from `iterator.remove();`. I scaled down your problem in my workspace and it is really not possible without `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, given the code you have provided.

Comment: @hagrawal Sorry pal, I'm not the OP ;-)

Comment: @Joffrey Thanks bud. Stand corrected.

Comment: @Joffrey I figured out the issue. Do you think i should post an answer or just delete the question? It is a pretty specific problem.

Comment: @kmecpp Well you should probably post an answer for starters, then people might think it is too specific, but you never know ;-)

Comment: @hagrawal I will in a bit, need to eat something first lol

Comment: @hagrawal There we go. Got caught up in some more work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had put the code for removing the players from the list in a pre-existing method that was called indirectly by the `closeScreen` method.

The reason why I say indirectly because all the `closeScreen` method does is update the player's current GUI 'container'. What I didn't realize is that the player is updated in a separate thread and once the player gets updated a GUI change is detected and it calls a 'GuiClose' method for the container. The problem is that this just happens to be where I put the code for removing the players from the list when they are no longer using the GUI. How I fixed this was simply making sure that the player is actually just closing the GUI and that its not my code forcing all the players to exist.

What really got me was that the closeScreen method is completely ambiguous, all it seems to be doing is changing the players open container variable so I didn't see how that could possibly be immediately closing the players GUI. The behavior that also hid this multi-threaded nature was that the player is updated almost immediately after calling `closeScreen` and this happens very consistently just after my first iteration to invoke the method on all the players. Which makes it even harder to find because you need multiple players using the GUI, if there's just one player, there will only be one iteration and the code will seem to work fine. Please edit or comment some suggestions for clarification in case I didn't explain this clearly enough.

Comment: Going by the Your Explanantion .. I guess Ankur Anand answer was helpful ..then

Answer (score 0):

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent
>   modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

So One of the possible reason.

```
player.closeScreen();
```

is trying to modify a Collection while another `iterator.remove();` is iterating over it.

Comment: The reason why i previously believe this wasn't the issue was because as I stated in my question, i never made the EntityPlayer class so I didn't see how it could be modifying my list. But then i realized that the closeScreen might somehow be invoking the method I'm using to remove the players from the list. I am testing that now and then i will update my question